# Unresolved externals using boost::asio(visual studio12, x64)

Tags: c++, boost, linker, boost-asio

I've downloaded and installed the boost_1_55_0-msvc-12.0-64.exe executable from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.55.0-build2/.

I extracted the binaries to C:\boost_1_55_0 and added the include and linker directories to visual studio project properties.

Include directory: c:\boost_1_55_0
Link directory: c:\boost_1_55_0\lib64-msvc-12.0

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::system::error_code::error_code(void)"
>   \error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::generic_category(void)" (?generic_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::system::`dynamic initializer for 'errno_ecat''(void)" (??__Eerrno_ecat@system@boost@@YAXXZ)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to make sure, what version of MSVC are you using?

Comment: sorry I made a mistake in the topic. Using Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 2):

You're probably using the 32 bit compiler / linker, since you downloaded the 64 bit libs make sure you invoke the 64 bit compiler.

Comment: thanks, problem solved, the error seem like not so obvious to point out the issue